# Visual Studio 2010 - Publishing a Windows Form or WPF application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, publish

I've been looking around and other than: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx I have found no information on how to publish a Windows form application I have written.

I have managed to publish and then install my application on my local computer, but not in the way I had intended. I was hoping to be able to zip up the folder containing my published project and upload it somewhere, at which point people can download the zip file and install my application. The publishing wizard doesn't  seem to be able to publish in such a way, or if it is, it is fairly unclear.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I can also clarify what I would like to do if need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create Setup Project ( File-> New -> Project -> Other Project Type -> Setup and Deployment -> Visual Studio Installer -> Setup Project ). So, in Solution Explorer, you can add existing project. After add your project, you can add your program output in File System window( Right click on Application Folder -> Add -> Project Output ... ), so you select your project from Project ComboBox ). After adding your project output, you can build your setup-project and you will have your setup file in your setup-project. 
For more information you can check :

[Steps to Create Setup and Deployment](http://www.fordevs.com/2009/07/steps-to-create-setup-and-deployment-project-in-dot-net-vs-2008.html)

[Setup Projects](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/8f7a3d05-a2df-41ac-bacd-e4ab4a289578)

Comment: Went ahead and played with what I had done earlier and got it to work, but this seems like a fairly complete answer.

Comment: What if project is database driven? suppose I am using EF code first?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way: [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (Too simple, free, many ability like Update )

> Edit : Absolutely there are many ways, also you can use third party software (like [InstallSheild](http://www.installshield.com/)). and Look at [Different Windows Installer and ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a setup-project - with this you can simply compile a setup and deploy all the setupfiles/msi and the user can install from this.