# C# application deployment with sql server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Can anyone tell me the accurate way of deployment my C# application with a SQL Server database? I want to run my application on client's machine, it is running on my machine but showing error on client's machine. I have already installed SQL Server 2012 on client's machine. I know little about deployment as I am  doing it for the first time. I know there is a need to attach `.mdf` file first. Please tell me the exact steps of deployment so that I am able to run my application on client's machine. The thing I need to mention is that the application is simple windows based application!

Comment: "but showing error on client's machine "......what error ?[You can create Setup Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298593/3089494)

Comment: Error was "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections".

Comment: where do you specified your connection string? have you successfully restored your database in your client machine?if its not take backup of the db  and restore it in client.

Comment: Connection string should be in a seperate config file. Edit it to the new connection string of your client machine.

Comment: Connection string is already in separate file but i did not know that i need to take backup of database and restore it on client's machine .Is this necessary ?

Comment: @SaadAhmed No, the database will MAGICALLY appear on the client computer without you actually creating or deploying it. Come on, use some sense here. How you think the tables and index definitions will magically appear on the client?

Comment: Give him a break.  We've all been this clueless at some stage... Well most of us.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/connection-strings-explained/

Comment: Creating a new database then restoring a backup or attaching the mdf should result in the same thing, you should be able to view the database in SQL Management studio on the client's machine.  If you can see the database in SQL Management studio then it is most probably your connection string that is the issue

Comment: Well thanks Mick..It means i have to take database backup from my machine and restore it on clients machine ??

Comment: Yes. you are right! Hope you know how to take a database backuop using SSMS

Comment: @anees ..Yes i know that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Attach database to the SQL Server instance (Either using .mdf and .ldf files or using a DB backup)

2 - Change your connection string before deploying the application in client machine. If you don't have a config file and you've hard coded the connection string then you'll have to change the connection string to reflect client's machine name, SQL Instance name and DB name and compile the application before deploying.

You may refer to the following URL to get an idea how to configure your connection string.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on your Project and add an existing item and browse to your
   database’s `.mdf` file  and select it.
2. When you successfully added the .mdf in your project you will be
   able to see it in the solution explorer. Now go back to Properties
   -> Settings and write “ConString” under the Name column. Select (Connection String)
   from the Type drop down. Select Application from the Scope drop down. Now
   in the Value column click to select the Database file. First select
   Server Name and then Attach a Database file -> Select your `.mdf` file
   you just added to your Project.
   [image]
3. You can now use this connection string in your code like this:

   ```
   Properties.Settings.Default.ConString;
   ```

   This connection string will be like:

   ```
   “Data Source=GAMING;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\management_system.mdf;Integrated Security=True”
   ```

   So when you produce the `.exe` file or setup file of your application your database file will be packaged with it and stored in the |DataDirectory| on your client PC and the connection string will access your database file just like that and your application will work on any PC given that SQL server is installed. I have not found a way to not to install SQL server on client PC and still run the application. If I do find it in the future, I will post it here :P

Answer (score 0):

You can probably look at the account used in the connection string.

I suspect that you were using a windows account to access the database on your computer while you haven't added a windows account to the SQL server on the client's computer.

So if you use an SQL user to login to the SQL studio management, you can use this login in your connection string. Or just simply add a default windows account login to SQL.