# How to deploy application to many users

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have got a C# .NET application which uses an SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

I have no problem deploying the actual application to multiple PCs, however I am having a whole world of trouble deploying the database.  The application is going to be used by a large amount of users - it can be downloaded and installed by anyone.  My problem is that the application uses a connection string to connect to the database.

How am I going to include the database as part of the installation using the Visual Studio publish tool, and make sure that it will work on any installation with the same connection string.

I have spent a long time searching, and have tried out many potential solutions, including [this, however in the latter particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470892/c-sharp-application-deployment-with-sql-server-database/24573521#24573521), the application could not find the database when it was deployed.

Comment: Do you want each user to connect to the same database or will everyone have his/her own database? In the second scenario you should use a database file that ships with the application or if it's not too complex, maybe consider another file type, such as xml.

Comment: @Sami - I want each user to use their own database, and bundle it somehow.  I have tried the solution in the link posted above, however it did not work.

Comment: Please post your connection string.

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Comment: Also, to clarify, I have installed SQL Server 2012 LocalDb on the users' PCs @Sami

Answer (score 0):

As per your given SQL connection, it seems your are using Sql Server Express edition, to bundle express edition with your application, here are the options,

1. Add SQL Server Expression edition setup in your installation media, and invoke setup.exe through your setup program
2. Or you can use Web Platform Installer
3. Or you can simply check in your setup program, whether desired SQL Server Express Edition is installed, if NOT then display the message to user that "Please install the Sql Server Express Edition", and guide how he/she can install, for example providing a download link

Or you can go with Sql Server Compact Edition which is a light weight version and I think only few DLLs are required to make it functional on end user's PC.

For more information:

**Sql Server Express Edition:**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/user_ed/archive/2012/12/09/how-to-embed-sql-server-express-in-an-application.aspx

**Sql Server Compact Edition:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: I have SQL Server 2012 Express on my development machine - does that mean that I need to install the same version on the users' PCs? I have installed SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB so far on a test user's PC, however there is a network/instance problem when I try to load the application.

Comment: Make sure you have installed Sql Server Express Edition properly, and also you can test the connection using Visual Studio or Sql Server Management Studio. Network / instance error is indicating either service is NOT running or there is a problem in your connection string

Comment: I have now removed SQL Express LocalDB and tried going for the SQL Compact approach, however the same thing is happening.  Kindly note that on my development PC, there is no problem connecting to the database with that connection string.  So I dont think the problem is from there

Comment: Try connecting Visual Studio / Management Studio on test machine

Comment: I mean on testing PC, where you are facing problem, you should have Sql Server Management Studio installed, and then use Management Studio to connect to Sql Express / Compact edition, in this way you will know whether your DB server is OK or not.